# Which IP will be sent to Website owner if i use file_get_contents or cURL with PHP to get some string

Tags: php, curl, server, cloudflare, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents` and `cURL` in PHP to get some string from third-party domains. I am using Cloudflare services with my website.

Let say, my website `domain.com` using `cURL` or `file_get_contents` to get some string from `example.com`

```
string = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com');
```

Let say, my server IP is `198.162.1.3` and cloudflare randomly changing IP is `122.5.66.3`. Now my question is the owner of the `example.com` able to see my server IP `198.162.1.3` or cloudflare IP `122.5.66.3`

Comment: Normally if you use file_get_contents / curl to access a website behind cloudflare, the website owner will see the cloudflare ip (122.5.66.3) as the source of the request because cloudflare acts as a reverse proxy. it acts as an intermediary between your server and the origin server.

Comment: They'll see whatever IP is the one which is publicly exposed to the internet. So in this case, very likely the cloudflare one. The other one looks like it's probably a local LAN IP used by a simple domestic router and issued via DHCP. It's not intended to be public, and likely it's not unique across the wider internet. It certainly isn't ping-able from where I am located now, whereas the Cloudflare one I can get a response from.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your situation. If it is about performing a curl request on server A to server B, and server B's domain is behind Cloudflare, if server A's curl performs a DNS lookup which thus routes through CF, server B will see one of Cloudflare's IPs as the requesting IP and the origin IP will be in the `CF-Connecting-IP` header. If it is about server A performing a curl request to server B, and server A's domain is behind CF, server B will see A's public egress IP address since CF is not involved in server-outbound.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?